# Center page as a whole without centering each element individually

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have some narrow text and tabular environments that I'd like to center based on the horizontal space they use up in total. However, it's important that when centered, the original alignments between the elements are preserved. So the effect would be more like increasing margins. Naturally, `\centering` won't work, as it centers every element individually.

The closest I've come is using a `minipage` and scaling the width by eye. The total width of the page content might vary though. So is there a way to do this kind of centering?

I guess if there's a way to measure the total width that a page takes, it could be fed to `minipage`. I have very little experience with LaTeX macros and what's generally possible. So any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here's an example.

[image: Situation now]

[image: Wanted result]

---

And a minimal code with all cases:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

Intro

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    C & C \\
\end{tabular}

Juttu

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
\end{tabular}

\centering
Intro

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    C & C \\
\end{tabular}

Juttu

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
\end{tabular}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

    Intro

    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        C & C \\
    \end{tabular}

    Juttu

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
        C & C & Am & G \\
        C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
        C & C & Am & G \\
        C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your issue.

Comment: If you can provide the code that produces the above content, one could better assist you with ideas on how to centre the content.

Comment: @leandriis Added.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for adding the example. If I understand you correctly, you basically would like to achieve the result in the third example?

Comment: @leandriis Correct, the second one is the attempt using `centering`, which I'm sure you see is not the proper output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `minipage` you could use a `varwidth` environment - this will automatically shrink to the necessary width:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

    Intro

    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        C & C \\
    \end{tabular}

    Juttu

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
        C & C & Am & G \\
        C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
        C & C & Am & G \\
        C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well damn, yet again I'm not alone with my problems. Simple. Effective. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix You're welcome! Thanks to the nice MWE you prepared, this was easy to answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would just set the constructions inside a `tabular` (that doesn't have any column padding, although that's necessary). The `tabular` will expand as needed, ultimately representing an unbreakable box that you can centre:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
  Intro \\
  \\
  \begin{tabular}{ l | l }
    C & C
  \end{tabular} \\
  \\
  Juttu \\
  \\
  \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l }
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C \\
    C & C & Am & G \\
    C Dm & C & C \quad G G & C
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Having the line breaks everywhere bothers me a bit. Maybe too much. But yeah, didn't think of that, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Maybe one could also use `Intro \\[\parskip]` instead of `Intro \\ \\ `?